# Rsync error. Could not start Rsync service on Local Computer

Tags: windows, rsync

I am facing a problem:

```
Could not start Rsync service on Local Computer.
Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

Can some body please help me on this?

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance.", please don't do it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the installation, you may have seen where it prompted for a user-name and password with the default user-name and password already typed in. You need to change this to that of the user you are logged in as. If you are logged in as administrator then enter the admin credential